# No Polish characters in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, encoding

I have WPF project with a service-based SQL Server database. I'm using O/R Designer.

I can add records to the database without problems, but words in database are without Polish characters (for example is "Zdzblo" instead "Źdźbło")

I tried something like that:

```
[ShortName] TEXT COLLATE sql_polish_cp1250_cs_as NOT NULL,
[Name] TEXT COLLATE sql_polish_cp1250_cs_as NULL,
```

and that:

```
[Nazwa] TEXT COLLATE Polish_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[NazwaSkrocona] TEXT COLLATE Polish_CI_AS NULL,
```

and it doesn't works.

I tried to change the database language:

```
USE DatabaseName ;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 14 ;
GO

RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

but still nothing.

Maybe the problem is O/R designer?

I have no more ideas. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: Do you use unicode prefix when inserting? for example: INSERT INTO tbl(A) VALUES(N'any unicode string')

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is change collection settings by Microsoft SQL Management Studio. I solve 
store Polish char problem like this.

Comment: Hi, can you add more detail like what to change and how you have overcome a similar problem faced by you? It is to help others accessing this same question in the future to not be confused or loose their way:)

Comment: with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 1- right click on your db. Click options on left menu. From Collection change to Polish_CI_AS

Comment: @SemihCanBilgen It doesn;t work for me, any other workaround? I cannot put polish chars into any table

Comment: @Arie I develop a project for Polish company and i solve this problem apply above process.